# Html Sections or Divs are not connecting with each other in columns?

Tags: html, css

I am developing a static website using HTML and CSS. The website is one-pager and I'm using sections to differentiate between all the content or parts if it's the right word. But I am facing a problem of moving into a third part. The first two parts look like below. Please see the image.

[image]

I am facing the problem when I try to make another section or third part after these two. I am trying to do something like this

[image]

but every time I try something I keep getting something like this. I don't want to use a lot of css for this to take it on the right place. Here is the image of what I am getting.

[image]

My Code what I am trying to do with CSS and HTML is below..

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Section1 -->
    <section class="">
      <div class="headerPosition">
        <img src="./assets/HeaderImage2.jpg" class="headerImage1" />
        <div class="ehrlich-top-left" style="color: white">Example</div>
        <!-- <img class="headerOnImage" src="./assets/rectangle1.jpg"> -->
        <div class="opacityClass"></div>

        <div class="opacityClass1"></div>
        <div class="ehrlich-Center">
          Example
        </div>
        <div class="centered">
          WIR MACHEN &nbsp;ARBEITGEBER
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section2 -->
    <section class="">
      <div class="col-background">
        <hr
          style="background-color:black; width: 5%; float: left; top:8%; position: absolute;"
        />
        <h1 class="content_app_vertical">ÜBER UNS</h1>
        <h1 class="content_app">
          Was machen wir?
          <hr style="background-color:black; width: 20%" align="left" />
        </h1>
        <p class="container_content_app">
          Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum
          Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum
          Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem
          Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem
          Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum Lorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsum v vLorem
          Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum IpsumLorem Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum IpsumLorem
          Lorem Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Ipsumv
        </p>

        <img class="content_pic" src="./assets/wasmachen.jpg" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Section3 -->
    <section>
      <div class="big_box"></div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Style.css**

```
.rectangle1 {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

.headerPosition {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.headerImage1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.headerOnImage {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1600px) {
  .ehrlich-Center {
    top: 30% !important;
  }
}

.ehrlich-Center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: White;
  width: 413px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100px;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 51%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  width: 413px;
  height: 30px;
  font-family: "PT Sans";
  font-size: 30px;
}

.ehrlich-top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.col-background {
  background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.15);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.col-background-2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.content_app {
  left: 20%;
  top: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "PT Sans" !important;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 3.5rem !important;
}

.opacityClass {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.75);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.75;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}

.opacityClass1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 155px;
  left: 80px;
  width: 85%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  border: solid white;
}

.opacityClass2 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 211%;
  left: 130px;
  width: 85%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  border: solid red;
}

.container_content_app {
  width: 452px;
  height: 277px;
  left: 20%;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: "PT Sans" !important;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content_app_vertical {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  float: left;
  left: -50px;
  margin: 0;
}

.content_pic {
  top: 20%;
  left: 60%;
  position: relative;
  width: 446px;
  height: 356px;
}

@media (max-width: 1500px) {
  .container_content_app {
    top: 35% !important;
  }
  .content_app_vertical {
    top: 35% !important;
  }
  .content_pic {
    width: 355px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}

.big_box {
  width: 1316px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 356px;
  position: absolute;
  /* left: 10%;
  top: 190%; */
}
.box {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: If you want matching columns, you should check flex methods.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Or buy a template, you'll spare lot of time and it'll be responsive.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But is there any way of doing it if I want to develop a website from scratch just like this?

Comment: Also you should post a [reprex], not you some code snippets and assume we get the picture... And search for 'free landing page template' will yield more than you bargained for....

Comment: @Khan to apply flex-box in an easy way you can take a look to that app https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/. Adding a couple of properties in the parent and child elements you could do it. It looks like a little complicated but is very easy to understand and apply.

Comment: @RenevanderLende I believe the code I posted is easy to understand and minimal for the people who qualified for the modern technologies. As I said, I know I can search for free templates, but I think for learning you should do on your own. And that's what I am doing. :)